# iTunes Still Charging per Track While Subscribed to Apple Music

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

I'm an Apple Music subscriber but I clicked an iTunes link from a website and now all albums have prices. My Apple Music subscription is active, I can stream all my Apple Music playlists and my phone works as expected, but iTunes is acting as though I am not subscribed.

In preferences Apple Music is selected:

[image]

However in iTunes I have a Store link and prices:

[image]

How do I get to the Apple Music subscription I'm paying for?

Comment: Interestingly, I can use my phone to find a track which iTunes is trying to charge me for and add it to My Music. This will then appear in the My Music tab of iTunes on my Mac so I can stream it in full... but if I choose Show Artist on that track it still has prices for everything, including the very track I was just streaming in full!  Something seems really messed up here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prices are shown because you are in the iTunes Store tab. You can still buy tracks and albums there, like before. To get to Apple Music, click "My Music", "For you" or "New" in the top bar.

"My music" is where your music is, both the tracks and albums you've previously purchased and the ones you've saved in Apple Music. "For you" is personalized suggestions, and "New" is well, new music.

When you do a search from any of those tabs you can also choose to search Apple Music instead of just your own library.

Comment: Yes, it seems if I click the New tab and then search the tracks come up free, if I click the Store tab they come up with prices. Very confusing, clearly I don't want to pay for tracks again if I'm subscribed to get them free, hopefully they tidy this up in future releases.

Comment: @Andrew Well, there might be occasions where you *want* to buy the tracks anyway, for example to put them on a device where Apple Music is not available. They could certainly make it less confusing, though.

Comment: Why they don't have a tab called "Apple Music" I don't know. Or better yet if the tune is available on Apple Music just change the buy buttons to listen buttons. How are normal people supposed to work that out?